# Remove currency in stock price scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-analysis

I scrape an stock price from an website and the output ist e.g. "12 EUR". How can i remove the EUR from the string inpython , so that i can work with just the number?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to remove anything that is not a number.

```py
import re
stock = '12 EUR'
stock = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', stock)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
amount = "12 EUR"
amount.split(' ')[0]
```

Output:

```
'12'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following does not throw an exception when " EUR" is missing:

```
txt = '123 EUR'
txt = txt.strip(' EUR')
print(txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on [mismaahs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64031854/2529619), a general purpose solution that handles currencies and decimals is:

```
import re
stock = '1,234.56 EUR'
stock = re.sub('^0-9\.', '', stock)
```